# How to resolve the error "Currently composing another batch in this ComposablePartExportProvider. Only one batch can be composed at a time."

Tags: .net, mef

I am getting the following error in my application that leverages MEF:

> Currently composing another batch in
>   this ComposablePartExportProvider.
>   Only one batch can be composed at a
>   time.

There seems be very little information on how to fix this error, and not sure what other information I should provide to even garner some assistance.

Has anyone else received this error using MEF? If so, what were some of the ways you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that if you're trying to build lists of Exports to match Import types on the fly, `container.GetExports<T>().Select(y => y.Value)` works a lot better.

With `container.ComposeParts(...)` I had to have all sorts of `lock(){}` blocks and another thread to do the composing. `GetExports<>` doesn't seem to suffer from this.

Answer (score 0):

While initializing you composition container, there is a flag to enable thread-safe option. As soon as you enable this one, you do not need any custom lock mechanism

```
var c = new AggregateCatalog();
c.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog("MyAssemblyName"));
var container = new CompositionContainer(c, true); // true means that it is thread safe
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe there are too many threads are using this ComposeParts function at the same time,I just locked this this function ,threads can operate this function sychonized,it goes well.

```
class AAA{
private  static object obj=new object();
private CompositionContainer container ;
private void MefOpt()
{
    var c = new AggregateCatalog();
    c.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog("MyAssemblyName"));
    container = new CompositionContainer(c, true);
    }
  private void CompPrt()
{
  lock(obj)
{
    container.ComposeParts(this);
}
}
```

}